# How do I pick an arbitrary number of an element occurring many times in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have two variables holding a string each and an empty list:

```
a = 'YBBB'
b = 'RYBB'
x = []
```

I want to loop through each of the strings and treat each 'B' in the two lists as an independent element (wish I could just type a.('B') and b.('B'). What I actually want to do is loop through **b** and ask if each of the items in **b** are in **a**. If so, the length of the item in **b** (say'B') is checked for in **a**. This should give 3. Then I want to compare the lengths of the item in the two lists and push the lesser of the two into the empty list. In this case, only two 'B's will be pushed into **x**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension like following:

```
>>> [i for i in set(b) for _ in range(min(b.count(i), a.count(i)))]
['B', 'B', 'Y']
```

If the order is important you can use `collections.OrderedDict` for creating the unique items from `b`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> 
>>> [i for i in OrderedDict.fromkeys(b) for _ in range(min(b.count(i), a.count(i)))]
['Y', 'B', 'B']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer (I'm sorry for the late comment). This solved the problem, but I don't quite understand every bit of the code. What exactly does the underscore do in the list comprehension? Please answer here or point me to any resource that could be of help. Thanks again.

Comment: @Taiwosam That's only a way for refusing of preserving the throwaway  variable when you don't want to use if in your loop. That means your code doesn't has to do a variable assignment and calling the value another time which make a notable difference in performance ;-) specially when you are dealing with large data sets.

Answer (score -1):

This is useless text for the moderators.

```
import collections

a = 'YBBB'
b = 'RYBB'
x = []

a_counter = collections.Counter(a)
b_counter = collections.Counter(b)
print(a_counter)
print(b_counter)

for ch in b:
    if a_counter[ch]:
        x.append(min(a_counter[ch], b_counter[ch]) * ch)

print(x)

--output:--
Counter({'B': 3, 'Y': 1})
Counter({'B': 2, 'Y': 1, 'R': 1})
['Y', 'BB', 'BB']
```

Or, if you only want to step through each unique element in b:

```
for ch in set(b):
    if a_counter[ch]:
        x.append(min(a_counter[ch], b_counter[ch]) * ch)

print(x)

--output:--
['Y', 'BB']
```